# How to delete many to many relation objects in Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a model Post having many to many relation images.
When a post is deleted, I would like all associated images to be also deleted.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, blank = True, related_name = 'posts')
```

Are there something like models cascade options or I have to do something else?

Comment: When deleting related objects all related object are unlinked by default, if you want to remove the files from file system, then do it manually

Comment: Since you used m2m, an image can belong to many posts. So you want an image that belong to many posts to be deleted even though only one post was deleted?

Answer (score 0):

based on the docs  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

you can use

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
post.image_set.clear()
```

to delete  all images of post by id 1

If you delete an object Post then the images are deleted too

Comment: Should be just `images`, so `post.images.clear()`

Comment: you can read the link i provided for more clarification